# Strange box shown in a tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Why does the [alm](/questions/tagged/alm) tag have this empty box in it? A sponsored tag with a broken icon?

[image: alm tag showing a box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the sponsored tag has a broken icon.
The [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alm), which lists all the questions using that tag, has a space for sponsored links that appears only on sponsored tags, such as [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook), but it doesn't contain any link.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

It seems the tag has been set as sponsored, but the settings have not been completed.